# how to create "something" as a service with an openstack cloud?

Tags: java, web-services, service, cloud, openstack

i have successfully deployed an openstack cloud , and installed a Mysql database on a 
virtual machine.

i want to create a cloud service for my cloud users to store and retrieve data from that 
database. I know this may look silly but i'm just doing this for learning purposes.

I have deployed the cloud and now i want to do something with it, but i have no idea how.

is there any tutorial that explains how to create a cloud service ?

Comment: If you are trying to build a dbaas then look at trove project. But then why reinvent the wheel? you can clone and modify it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a particular programming language you'd prefer to use? Because I can point you based on that.

Comment: i prefer java as a programming language. thank you :)